# Setting up TLS issue

Tags: freeswitch, fusionpbx

I am trying to get TLS up and running on a multi domain server. The server has a valid commercial wildcard certificate up an running in Nginx which works fine.

I have done the following to get it up and running in the TLS folder

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.crt > /etc/freeswitch/tls/all.pem
cat /etc/ssl/private/mykey.key >> /etc/freeswitch/tls/all.pem

ln -s /etc/freeswitch/tls/all.pem /etc/freeswitch/tls/agent.pem
ln -s /etc/freeswitch/tls/all.pem /etc/freeswitch/tls/tls.pem
ln -s /etc/freeswitch/tls/all.pem /etc/freeswitch/tls/wss.pem
ln -s /etc/freeswitch/tls/all.pem /etc/freeswitch/tls/dtls-srtp.pem
chown -R www-data:www-data /etc/freeswitch/tls
```

I read somewhere it had to be the root CA & the cert which I have also tried

When I try to get it up and running though I get the following error is fs_cli

[ERR] sofia.c:3311 Error Creating SIP UA for profile: internal (sip:mod_sofia@ipaddress:5060;maddr=ipaddress;transport=udp,tcp). Bad WSS.PEM certificate